Crimping with long fingers
Posting here for the first time. I am seeking some advice regarding finger strength training and crimping, in general.
I have resumed climbing after a long break of six years. It has been about six months since I have got back to climbing. In the period of two years when I used to climb regularly, I never trained for finger strength specifically. No hangboarding, no finger boarding as such, but I gained finger strength just by climbing. Now that I have started climbing again after all this time, I have lost some finger strength obviously.
This time, however, I want to have a proper training plan for climbing. Currently, I am trying a boulder where the top move is a crimp, which I am failing at. Now I know that many a times, just climbing more improves crimping. Or at least many climbers advise so. However, I would like to know if there are some training methods that I can adopt to work on my crimping and finger strength.
Coming to the title of this post, I have noticed that when I go for a closed hand crimp, I end up hyperextending the DIP joints quite a bit. And I don't think of aggressive crimping as I have hurt myself in the past doing so. As far as training methods are concerned, I am aware of max hangs and fingerboards, but I want to know how someone with my anatomy (long fingers) should approach these methods. My questions are as follows -

What's the crimping experience of the climbers who have long finger?

While open hand crimp feels good, it produces less force. Should I train my open crimp to make it stronger or is there any way to train closed hand crimp without injuring myself?

In general, can there be climbs where I would NEED to do a closed/aggresive crimp or I can do just fine with an open crimp or a three finger drag, provided I train for it?


Thank you!

Dave McCleod recommends avoiding the full crimp AMAP and states that he thinks that the open fingers version can be as strong if properly trained. Certainly there seems to be a correlation of injury with full crimp but please accept that this comment comes with little to no substantiation.

Thanks, I will check out Dave McCleod

After a break of 6 years, there is probably not much conditioning left. This is even more true, when we consider that you have only climbed for 2 years prior to the break. Your most important goal now should be injury prevention, not building finger strength. No full crimping and no training above body weight. Your body will need 1-2 years of to adapt to the loads of climbing.
That said, you can still improve a lot. With a total climbing experience of 2,5 years, there is still plenty of room to improve your grade with technique. There is also plenty of room for improvement by training your core. Antagonist training is often overlooked but a vital component to improvement. Climbing trains almost exclusively pulling and you can only become so one-sided before you start running into problems.
As far as I know, there is no special training or technique for long fingers. There surely is a difference when it comes to very small holds, but for recreational climbing it does not really matter as recreational climbers are climbing far below their physical maximum.

@Willeke Re the deleted post below:  I am not a climber, so I cannot say anything about the substantive content of this answer.  However, I do understand English, and I find nothing abusive or offensive or spamish about this answer.  I suspect a not-intelligent AI judged this answer.

Thanks for your inputs, Manziel. For strength and conditioning , I am currently doing full body twice a week which includes weighted pull ups, weighted dips, bench press, squats and deadlifts, mainly. I am not full crimping during climbing. I have recently started doing "no hangs" repeaters. Any thoughts on this?

@ab2 if you’re talking about the other answer to this question (posted two days ago, deleted yesterday), you can see that the original answer was fine-ish, but then they edited in a spam link later. I see nothing wrong with Manziel’s answer, though.

@fyrepenguin  I thought that was just a weird typo, possibly produced by a cat on the keyboard.  Thanks for the explanation.
